# How to replace everything is left after space?

Tags: php, regex, string, explode

I want to replace everything that is left after space.
This is my code, and result will be "***13215.00 13195.00***"

```
<?php
function bacaHTML($url){
     $data = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     $hasil = curl_exec($data);
     curl_close($data);
     return $hasil;
}

$kodeHTML   = bacaHTML('http://www.thislink.com');
$pecah      = explode('<table width="139" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">', $kodeHTML);
$pecahLagi  = explode('</table>', $pecah[2]); *// result will be "USD 13215.00 13195.00 SGD 9778.82 9758.82 EUR 14966.37 14866.37 AUD 10092.31 10012.31"*

$ngilang    = substr($pecahLagi[0], 0, strpos($pecahLagi[0], 'SGD')); // result will be "USD 13215.00 13195.00"
$usdilang   = strtr($ngilang, array('USD' => '<replacement>')); // result will be "13215.00 13195.00"

echo $usdilang;

?>
```

Now, how that code is running so that the results will be "***13195.00***"

I try this but NOT work.

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $usdilang);
$secondPiece = $pieces[1];
echo $secondPiece;
```

Thank You.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: explode not working after $usdilang   = strtr($ngilang, array('USD' => '<replacement>'));

I try using this work $pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

but I try to this does not work
$pieces = explode(" ", $usdilang);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string by spaces.

```
$myString = "13215.00 13195.00";
$pieces = explode(" ", $myString);
$firstPiece = $pieces[0];
$secondPiece = $pieces[1];
```

Comment: Yes, but this not work. I try
$pieces = explode(" ", $usdilang);
$firstPiece = $pieces[0];
$secondPiece = $pieces[1];

echo $secondPiece;

and result Blank

Comment: @MrZy - `var_dump($usdilang);` and `var_dump($pieces);`

Comment: @devlin_carnate - `var_dump($usdilang);` result is `string(423) " 13215.00 13195.00 "`

Comment: @MrZy - Well, you have spaces before and after your numbers.  `var_dump($pieces);` and you will see that the values you want are in `$pieces[1]` and `$pieces[2]`